# error:no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

why this error occurs. I have already a database. And I add table and insert a item in it.I control this steps and when I insert item there is no error.But when I want to read which I put the item in my new table , this error occurs.It says I do not find.I control it in emulator , I push .db to my desktop and open it.I see in it and yes , there isn't the new table.But It must be.

When I remove app and re install my app there isn t any problem , the tables are there. But I DONT WANTTO RE-INSTALL i want to upgrade. What can I do for this?

```
package xxxxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME="xxx.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="already_exist";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2="already_exist2";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME3="new_table";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, s TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, a TEXT,v TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME3 + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, x TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

       }

}
```

Comment: Post the logcat and some code

Comment: I edit my question. and logcat says no such table (it says for new table)

Comment: I set my db version to 2 but dont fix my error this.

Comment: If you're running this into your Emulator. Just verify the table is there or not through your DDMS..

Comment: I edit my question.Look I try , ı write onupgrade block to my query but it isnt work again.

Comment: I know. There is db. But I want to add table to my exist db. How I add table to exist table?

Comment: change ur database and table name and clean project

Comment: its done. When I write onupgrade block it s done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME3 + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, x TEXT)");
   }


@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME3 + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, x TEXT)");
   }
```